# Format string to Datetime

Tags: sql, excel, oracle

I am currently in the process of creating a query on our Oracle DB in Microsoft Query. Somehow, I only get the date from the Oracle DB as a string. The format looks like this: "YYYY-DD-MM SS:MM:HH".
Excel recognizes the column at the end only as a string.
How can I have the column output directly in the date format "DD.MM.YYYY"?
Can I change the format directly via Select?

```
  SELECT 
    DB_Gen.STRT, 
    DB_Gen.SRST, 
    DB_Gen.DOCO, 
    DB_Gen.WR02, 
    DB_Gen.WR03, 
    DB_Gen.UORG, 
    DB_Gen.LITM
  FROM 
    MCC.POOLDB DB_Gen
  WHERE 
    (DB_Gen.WR03 Like 'G%') 
    AND (DB_Gen.MCU='AMC') 
    AND (DB_Gen.DCTO='WO') 
    AND (DB_Gen.WR01<>'EX') 
    AND (DB_Gen.STRT Between TRUNC(TO_DATE('01.01.2019','dd.mm.yyyy')) 
    AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('01.09.2019','dd.mm.yyyy')))
```

Do you even know how I can display the last 60 days?
So far, I'm only talking about Between and Trunc(TO_DATE .....

Best Regards
Joshua

Comment: It looks like you are looking for to_char function (select to_char(DB_Gen.STRT, 'DD.MM.YYYY') from MCC.POOLDB DB_den....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can display the last 60 days?

```
where DB_Gen.STRT >= trunc(sysdate) - 60
```

> How can I have the column output directly in the date format
>   "DD.MM.YYYY"?

```
select to_char(DB_Gen.STRT, 'DD.MM.YYYY') as strt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for

```
DB_Gen.STRT BETWEEN SYSDATE - 60 AND SYSDATE --Or CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

What I prefer is to set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` at session level to the desired format if I had to access dates in my query multiple times.

In your case, the following is my suggestion:

```
-- setting date format at session-level
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD.MM.YYYY'; 

SELECT 
    DB_Gen.STRT, -- this date will be populated in DD.MM.YYYY format in result
    DB_Gen.SRST, 
    DB_Gen.DOCO, 
    DB_Gen.WR02, 
    DB_Gen.WR03, 
    DB_Gen.UORG, 
    DB_Gen.LITM
  FROM 
    MCC.POOLDB DB_Gen
  WHERE 
    (DB_Gen.WR03 Like 'G%') 
    AND (DB_Gen.MCU='AMC') 
    AND (DB_Gen.DCTO='WO') 
    AND (DB_Gen.WR01<>'EX') 
    AND (TRUNC(DB_Gen.STRT) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-60) AND TRUNC(SYADATE);
-- Trunc is used to ignore time portion
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Hey Tejash! Thanks for the replay. Is this approach changing anything in the database? I just have read only rights.

Comment: Nope. It will not change anything at database level.

Comment: Alright, but I get an failure, that there is a missing or invalid option at the first line. Are there any specific syntax principles for microsoft query?

Comment: Ohho.. it is syntax of oracle SQL.

Comment: Is there any chance to get this approach in MS Query syntax?

Comment: I am not expert in MS SQL. Sorry!!